# SQL sub query select doubts

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

LogTable in SQL Server

```
timestamp                  user_name     session_id
2012-10-17 06:30:10        Sanjay        034A955F
2012-10-17 06:30:20        Sanjay        034A955F
2012-08-20 13:20:59        John          0547961A 
2012-08-20 13:21:05        John          0547961A 
2012-08-20 13:22:10        John          0547961A 
2012-10-17 04:02:10        John          0977661B
```

Desired output

```
user       Total_login      This_Month_Login   Recent_Login  
Sanjay     2                2                  2012-10-17 06:30:10 
John       4                1                  2012-10-17 04:02:10
```

I tried to write SQL SELECT query to get above output but I am not good in SQL so couldn't take it ahead and wrote only for 2 columns. Can you please help me to get above select output?

```
select user_name as 'User', count (distinct session_id) as 'Total_Login' 
from "LogTable" 
group by user_name
```

Comment: Do you need to count each record or only distinct session_id? If you need to count only disctint session_id then your output for Sanjay and John is incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this query

```
select
    T.user_name as User,
    count(distinct T.session_id) as Total_Login,
    count(distinct case when datediff(mm, T.timestamp, getdate()) = 0 then session_id else null end) as This_Month_Login,
    max(T.timestamp) as Recent_Login
from LogTable as T
group by T.user_name
```

I've made an assumption that you need to count only distinct session_id in your output.
If you not, than you need

```
select
    T.user_name as User,
    count(*) as Total_Login,
    count(case when datediff(mm, T.timestamp, getdate()) = 0 then 1 else null end) as This_Month_Login,
    max(T.timestamp) as Recent_Login
from LogTable as T
group by T.user_name
```

Comment: max will give "2012-10-17 06:30:20" but he says that he wants "2012-10-17 06:30:10".

Comment: no it's not, it's grouped by user_name so it will give max for each user_name

Comment: @MarkByers - I know this is an assumption, but I would place more money on `Typo` or `OP Error` than I would on that being a correct example output dataset.

Comment: @Dems: Yes... or missing specification, e.g. logins a few minutes after each other should be ignored in the calculation of `Recent_Login`? To be honest in these situations it's better to just ask the OP instead of guessing. Neither you or I know what is going through the OP's mind and there's no way to know unless he tells us.

Comment: I've asked :) Actually, I've wrote count(*), but then I've seen that OP wants distinct session_ids

Comment: @AlexAlexy: Then fix the question. No-one reads the comments to search for corrections to the question.

Comment: Thank you all. I modified the query given by Roman Pekar to get output select T.user_name as 'User',
    count(distinct T.session_id) as Total_Login,
    count(distinct case when datediff(mm, substring([timestamp],1,23), getdate()) = 0 then session_id else null end) as This_Month_Login,
    max(T.timestamp) as Recent_Login
from LogTable as T
group by T.user_name

Comment: I had to do substring as actual timestamp also had timezone

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE
  @this_month DATETIME
SELECT
  @this_month = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, getDate), 0)

SELECT
  user_name,
  COUNT(*)                                                  AS total_log,
  SUM(CASE WHEN timestamp >= @this_month THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS log_this_month,
  MAX(timestamp)                                            AS recent_login
FROM
  "LogTable"
GROUP BY
  user_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select 
    USER_NAME, 
    COUNT(*) As Total_login,
    COUNT(case when MONTH(getdate())=MONTH(tm) then 1 end) As This_Month_Login,
    MAX(tm) as Recent_Login
From MyTable
group by user_name 
order by user_name desc
```